# Pixel perfect graphics in Java swing/awt

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

Is there a way to achieve pixel perfect graphics in Swing/AWT components?

I am implementing a custom border for a button by extending `AbstractBorder`. For demonstration purpose thickness is always equal to 3 and each line is painted using different color.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.*;

public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame {

    public ExampleFrame() {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new CustomLookAndFeel());

        ExampleFrame frame = new ExampleFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton button1 = new JButton("aaa");
        button1.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
        button1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button1.setFocusable(false);

        constraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 3;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        panel.add(button1, constraints);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("bbb");
        button2.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        button2.setFocusable(false);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        panel.add(button2, constraints);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("eee");
        button3.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        button3.setFocusable(false);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        panel.add(button3, constraints);

        JButton button4 = new JButton("ddd");
        button4.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        button4.setFocusable(false);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        panel.add(button4, constraints);

        pack();
    }

    private static final class CustomBorder extends AbstractBorder {

        private final int thickness;

        public CustomBorder() {
            this(1);
        }

        public CustomBorder(int thickness) {
            this.thickness = thickness;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            //            ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);
            ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));

            for (int i = 0; i < thickness; i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 1: {
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2: {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                // top-left -> top-right
                g.drawLine(x, y + i, x + width, y + i);
                // top-left > bottom-left
                g.drawLine(x + i, y, x + i, y + height);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
            insets.top = thickness;
            insets.bottom = thickness;
            insets.left = thickness;
            insets.right = thickness;
            return insets;
        }
    }

    private static final class CustomLookAndFeel extends BasicLookAndFeel {

        @Override
        protected void initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
            super.initComponentDefaults(table);

            // button
            Border buttonBorder = new CustomBorder(3);
            table.put("Button.border", buttonBorder);
            table.put("Button.background", new Color(150, 150, 182));
            table.put("Button.foreground", Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "custom";
        }

        @Override
        public String getID() {
            return "custom";
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "custom";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Even though all 3 buttons have the same border parameters I get different border width and colors displayed.

VALUE_STROKE_PURE and VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE hints give different results, but none of them is pixel accurate.

[image: VALUE_STROKE_PURE]
[image: VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE]

Buttons "bbb", "eee" and "ddd" on the right side have the same width and height, but still the colors and total width of the border is different. Additionally, the default stroke that is being used has width of 1.0f.

I assume this happens, because Java 2D geometry operates on floating point numbers. Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

I tried different routines e.g. drawRect and different anti-aliasing hints, but no luck.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  In Java 14 on Linux, each line is exactly one pixel thick for me.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem exists in JDK 11.0.7. on Windows 10. However, you are right. On JDK 1.8.0_221 the border displays correctly regardless of stroke hint. Initially looks like https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241561 this issue, but this has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Instead of using the drawLine function use fillRect and specify the bounds explicitly

Comment: I use JDK11.0.6 on Windows 10 and each line is a single pixel. I would find it surprising that is suddenly stops working in a single release. I suggest you simplify the MRE so that you don't use your custom LAF. Just set the Border manually on individual components. Try a JButton and JLabel. Also, try painting with the default properties of the Graphics object. If you ever do want to change the Graphics properties, then use: `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();` and paint with that object so you don't affect the painting of other components.

Comment: @weisj - tried drawRect, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @camickr - I would be surprised too that it works on your version, but the screen capture is real. I guess I have to take "it works for me". BTW. I'm working on a brand new LAF so I don't want to set certain properties directly (that's the point of LAF). Thanks for the hint with #create() - forgot about that.

I'm good for now that it works in JDK8 on Windows 10 and I can progress.

Comment: @DrBoom, *BTW. I'm working on a brand new LAF so I don't want to set certain properties directly (that's the point of LAF* - I understand what you are doing for your application. My point is that an MRE is NOT about your application. The MRE attempts to demonstrate a problem so it should be a simple as possible. As I suggested a couple of components and the custom border code. You want to eliminate the possibility that the custom LAF causes the problem. So the MRE should not include the custom LAF.

Comment: @camickr - oh right, I see your point. I tried that before, but this wasn't obvious from the example and I did not mention it.

Comment: @DrBoom No not `drawRect`. It suffers from the same problems as `drawLine`. You should be using `fillRect`!